# How can I change Android Leanback library to support a background video instead of background image

Tags: android, android-videoview, leanback

I am trying to figure out how to modify the leanback sample app to play a different video as each card is selected. Currently there is drawable which changes as a card is selected. I want to play a video instead while still having the selection cards being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no video support in the background manager API

Setup a video player along with your root view so you can play show player and play the video when the URL is navigating to a video and set background image when its image URL.